# I am trying to generate my signed app bundle but I am getting the error: Circular dependency between the following tasks:

Tags: android, wear-os

**I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 and I read to disable Instant Run, but I think this is no longer an option. The app is a standalone wear app.

**UPDATE:**
if I remove the line wearApp project(":wear")from the gradle file the circular dependency error is gone but I get the error:
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed"
for all of my views.**

Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:wear:compileReleaseArtProfile
--- :wear:mergeDexRelease
--- :wear:dexBuilderRelease
+--- :wear:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
|    +--- :wear:dataBindingGenBaseClassesRelease
|    |    +--- :wear:mergeReleaseResources
|    |    |    +--- :wear:generateReleaseResources
|    |    |    |    --- :wear:handleReleaseMicroApk
|    |    |    |         --- :wear:packageRelease
|    |    |    |              +--- :wear:compileReleaseArtProfile (*)
|    |    |    |              +--- :wear:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac (*)
|    |    |    |              +--- :wear:mergeDexRelease (*)
|    |    |    |              +--- :wear:optimizeReleaseResources
|    |    |    |              |    --- :wear:processReleaseResources
|    |    |    |              |         +--- :wear:mergeReleaseResources (*)
|    |    |    |              |         +--- :wear:parseReleaseLocalResources
|    |    |    |              |         |    --- :wear:packageReleaseResources
|    |    |    |              |         |         +--- :wear:generateReleaseResources (*)
|    |    |    |              |         |         --- :wear:handleReleaseMicroApk (*)
|    |    |    |              |         +--- :wear:processReleaseManifest
|    |    |    |              |         |    --- :wear:processReleaseMainManifest
|    |    |    |              |         |         --- :wear:handleReleaseMicroApk (*)
|    |    |    |              |         --- :wear:processReleaseManifestForPackage
|    |    |    |              |              --- :wear:processReleaseManifest (*)
|    |    |    |              +--- :wear:processReleaseManifestForPackage (*)
|    |    |    |              --- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)
|    |    |    --- :wear:handleReleaseMicroApk (*)
|    |    --- :wear:parseReleaseLocalResources (*)
|    --- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)
--- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {

    namespace 'com.kingandy.pickleballwatch'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kingandy.pickleballwatch"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.2.0'
    wearApp project(":wear")
}
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />

    <!--
           Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
           app to run.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I had to remove     wearApp project(":wear")  and then synchronice the debug and main res folders to get rid of the resource linking error